# How can I make Math.random call a different value everytime it is called in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, math, random

Let's say I had something like what's below in a function, the first time it gets called, I have a random value, but every other time it's called, I get the same number as it spit out the first time. What can I do to ensure it is randomized each time it is called?

```
if (Cosmo.hitTestObject(Asteroid5))
    {



        Asteroid5.y = (Math.random() * 20 - 5);
        Asteroid5.x = (Math.random() * 20 - 15);
        Asteroid5.x = Asteroid5.x + (Math.random() * 20 - 15);
        Asteroid5.y = Asteroid5.y + (Math.random() * 20 - 5);
    }
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that `Math.random()` is returning the same values multiple times? (ie. have you added some trace statements to check.) Because that is definitely *not* how `Math.random()` normally works.

Comment: Seems correct. Maybe it's a problem with the two Asteroid5 objects you're using. How about a full working example?

Comment: I suspect something else is resetting your asteroid positions. Are you setting their initial positions as variables on one frame, then going back to that frame later?

Comment: No , but I have screwed up with my layers a bit, I posted this in a comment to the first answers, but I'll copy and paste it here. " I know that my Math.randoms are in my function, so they should be different each time they're called, right? Maybe it's within my layers, in my main layer I have a speed value set to each object, then in a different layer (long story as to why i did this) I have an if statement saying, if this object is hit, assign it a random x and y value. Could that be causing the issue?"In response to @caerolus Define what you mean by a working example, do you need more code?

Comment: Also, I haven't used a trace element yet, but you're right, there could be something else resetting the asteroid's movement, but i'm not sure what that'd be, I haven't written anything in to do that.

Comment: The reason I think the timeline might be involved is that `MovieClip`s that are added to the timeline manually get their positions reset if you go to a frame without them, then return to the frame where they were placed.

Comment: Well, basically, the game is collecting asteroids and when I collect an asteroid, I do NOT change frames, it should simply reset the asteroids position and speed with new, random values. If i'm hit by a large asteroid, the scene will change, and yes the smaller asteroids positions are reset, but this is okay. Could the fact that I'm using 2 different layers have an effect on it?

Comment: Possibly. Code on different layers behaves as if it's all in one block, just with higher up layers running first. If there are naming conflicts maybe that's why it's acting strangely. This sort of confusing debugging is why people try to avoid coding on the timeline! Try tracing out your asteroid positions in different places to see if you can find out what's really happening.

Comment: Alright, also, (Really sorry for the rookie questions) How do I not code on the timeline? Or does that simply mean put all your code in Frame 1?

Comment: There's a basic introduction [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ec0.html). But essentially for your main class, you assign a text file called something like `Main.as` as the "Document Class" for the whole swf, instead of spreading the code across different frames. For now though, I hope you can edit your question after narrowing down the problem a  bit more.

Answer (score 1):

[Edited, based on comments below]
The AS3 reference page for Math.random() says:

> Returns a pseudo-random number n, where 0 <= n < 1. The number
>   returned is calculated in an undisclosed manner, and is
>   "pseudo-random" because the calculation inevitably contains some
>   element of non-randomness.

If you want to use a seed-based pseudo-random number generator, this should help you:

http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?365564-AS3-Seeded-Pseudo-Random-Number-Generator

Comment: This is a mis-representation of the facts. The [AS3 docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#random()) indicate that `Math.random()` has no seed and returns a psuedo-random number between 0 and 1. There should, theoretically, be no need to seed.

Comment: I believe you misunderstand how pseudo-random number generators work. They will generate a number using a formula that uses the previously-generated value. Thus, if the first value is "seeded" explicitly by the user, a different sequence can be generated (as opposed to getting the exact same values, in the exact same order, every time you call Math.random()).

Comment: It's highly unlikely :-). There'll be an internal seed in the class; a timestamp of some description most likely. I don't think Adobe released a psuedo-random number generator that always returned the same number...

Comment: That is exactly how the C/C++ standard library PRNGs work. However, I ran some AS3 code to check, and you are right :)  Adobe baked the seed into the class. I don't know how OP got the same result every other time.

Comment: Well, despite the fact that it isn't working properly (evidently) I decided to go with a timer like Ben advised and use it as a sort of seed, currently all my objects dissapear after a hit test and don't come back, but it's probably just a logic issue I screwed up. I'll report back if it works, choose this as the best answer and close the question.

Comment: The results you get would indicate a fundamental problem with your code @user2072135; faking a random number generator isn't the best way to go. You get two random numbers at almost the same time. The time won't have changed that much between doing it. You're going to end up with two, almost identical, "random" numbers. You need to find out _why_ it's happening.

Comment: Good point, I'm a real rookie programmer, so I haven't a clue at the moment, I know that my Math.randoms are in my function, so they should be different each time they're called, right? Maybe it's within my layers, in my main layer I have a speed value set to each object, then in a different layer (long story as to why i did this) I have an if statement saying, if this object is hit, assign it a random x and y value. Could that be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

in your 1st 2 statements, it looks like you're using Asteroid5.y & Asteroid5.x as variables. so one idea would be to use variables of the correct type (i'm assuming it's Number):

```
var rndX:Number = (Math.random() * 20 - 15); 
var rndY:Number = (Math.random() * 20 - 5); 
var rndX2:Number = rndX + (Math.random() * 20 - 15);
var rndY2:Number = rndY + (Math.random() * 20 - 5);
Asteroid5.x = rndX2;
Asteroid5.y = rndY2; or
var rndX:Number;
var rndY:Number;
for ( var i:uint=0; i<2; i++ )
{
   rndX += (Math.random() * 20 - 15);
   rndY += (Math.random() * 20 - 5);
}
Asteroid5.x = rndX;
Asteroid5.y = rndY;
```

now you can step through your code in debug mode and see exactly what going on as the values of the variables change. also maybe search your code for 'Asteroid5.x =' & 'Asteroid5.y =' & 'Asteroid5.y=' & 'Asteroid5.x='